# Show progress on Flyway

Tags: java, jsf, flyway

I have a JSF App, which uses Flyway to update the database.

After the user has logged in, a method is called that checks if there are scripts and then starts to execute them through Flyway.

```
private void updateDB() {
    status = Status.PROCESSING;

    DataSource ds = getDataSource();

    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();

    flyway.setDataSource(ds);
    flyway.setInitOnMigrate(true);
    flyway.setLocations(PROTOCOL + SCRIPTS_DB_MIGRATION);
    flyway.setOutOfOrder(true);

    try {
        flyway.migrate();
        deletaScripts();
        status = Status.UPDATING;
    } catch (FlywayException e) {
        status = Status.FAILED;
        e.printStackTrace();
        createZipperLog();
    }
}
```

Meanwhile the user is sent to a loading page.

I'd like to know how could I put some listener or something else to show the user which script is being executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Flyway 3.0, you can implement [`FlywayCallback`](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/api/callback/FlywayCallback.html) to hook into the lifecycle and get the info you need.